# Data studio connector using two api keys to authenticate

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to build a connector that needs to access an API which requires **API_KEY** and **API_SECRET**. Currently Data Studio doesn't support authentication with two keys. So I thought I'd use auyhentication type **NONE** and then in **getConfig()** function I would prompt the user to input two required keys. However it seemms an awkward thing to do so I am asking more experienced developers. Am I introducing any security issue here? From what I understand there is no deifference whether I check and store user credentials in **getConfig()** or **setCredentials()**. They all end up stored in **PropertiesService** so I don't see any major difference. However, I may be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently(Nov 2019) there isn't support for API_KEY+API_SECRET. You have a few alternatives:

1. Use USER_PASS and in the connector description, instruct the user to use API_KEY for USER and API_SECRET for PASS.
2. Use NONE and get the info in getConfig().

Until the Data Studio team implements a solution, I recommend using #1. This will make it easier for you to migrate code and existing users once an official solution becomes available.